# System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS

Tags: apex, email, visual-workflow, apex-email-service, developer

i am calling apex email class from the flow with passing 4 parameters

[image]

Here to this apex class

```
 public with sharing class opportunityFulfillmentEmail {
    
    @InvocableMethod 
    public static void sentCsmEmail(List <flowInput> requests ) {
         
        
        flowInput req = requests[0];
        
        
          List<string> toAddress = new List<string>(req.primaryEmail);
          List<string> toCCAddress = new List<string>(req.CcEmail);
          ID conId = req.contactId;
        
        // Query the fields we need to merge 
          Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, Billing_Contact_FirstName__c,Buying_Contact_FirstName__c 
                              FROM Opportunity 
                              WHERE Id=:req.oppId];
        // Query the email template
          EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [SELECT Id,Subject,Body,HtmlValue
                                          FROM EmailTemplate
                                          WHERE Id=:req.templateId
                                          LIMIT 1];
        // Process the merge fields  
          String plainBody = emailTemplate.Body;
          plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Billing_Contact_FirstName__c}', opp.Billing_Contact_FirstName__c);                             
          plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Buying_Contact_FirstName__c}', opp.Buying_Contact_FirstName__c); 
          
          String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue;
          htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Billing_Contact_FirstName__c}', opp.Billing_Contact_FirstName__c);
          htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Buying_Contact_FirstName__c}', opp.Buying_Contact_FirstName__c);

        // Build the email message
          Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
         
          message.setTemplateID(emailTemplate.Id);
          message.setSubject(emailTemplate.Subject);
          message.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);
          message.setHTMLBody(htmlBody);
          message.setToAddresses(toAddress);          
          message.setCcAddresses(toCCAddress);
          message.setTargetObjectId(conId);
          
          Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { Message });


      }
      // Input details which comes to Apex class from flow 
     public class flowInput {
  
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public List<string> primaryEmail;

        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public List<string> CcEmail;
        
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public id oppId;

        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public id contactId;  

        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public id templateId;  

     } 
}
```

this the error that I get

[image]

Comment: What is your question? The error message is providing pretty clear guidance to the problem.

Comment: the list of emails is not null

Comment: did you check what email address coming in to Apexclasss by using `system.debug('emails'+ toCCAddress)` ?

Comment: it is retrun  |USER_DEBUG|[15]|DEBUG|primaryEmail(hamza.xxxxx@gmail.io, )

Answer (score 0):

The logs says: primaryEmail(hamza.xxxxx@gmail.io, )

And the error is: Email address is invalid: null: [ccAddresses, null]

The second email address in the list is null.

Comment: Now after doing some change in the code i got this error  : INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid: : [toAddresses, ]

Comment: It looks like the second element is not null anymore but the empty string. Your list of email addresses contains one to many addresses.

Comment: so i should clean the list from null and empty string using a if statement or remove (' ') and remove (Null) because I have tried  remove () and I got this error System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object